What could be the issue of burning of these capacitors asus gtx10XX series
I was using my Asus GTX 1060, normally until suddenly it made the PC shut, my motherboard may have had a protective layer that didn't allow my PC to turn on, I took my GPU to my friend to test it there and his PC + my GPU starts normally and I saw a spark on this capacitor, then GPU didn't work since then.
These capacitors burned (One of them has fallen because I touched it with multimeter pins)
What should I do to troubleshoot what could go wrong before replacing these capacitors?

Likely physical fracture caused by the board flexing when inserting/removing into/from pcie slot. MLCC's are very prone to fracturing, handle with care...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not sure if it's just the quality of the photo but that board looks like it's got some moisture damage, like it was in a humid environment. Can you get a clearer, better lit photo? Moisture can rot the solder joints to the point that components will come off the board.

@GodJihyo Yeah I live in city where humidty is higher, but I have tested 16 pcie input to the ground and everything seems fine except this MLCC which I saw maybe used as protection for GPU got burnt

In general, the underlying problem when an MLCC cap goes bad is that the cap has failed and needs to be replaced. As Unimportant commented, board flexing is a possible cause, but caps just sometimes fail for no apparent reason.

Thank you for your reply, I'll try to replace these both capacitors and try to run it, if it burn again I'll suspect that something is short-circuited that drain so much power
